# Getting black screen after merging my images in PHP

Tags: php

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxdaQ.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiiIx.png)

When I am merging the images I am getting the image like this:[merged image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGjpw.png)

Here is my code:

```
$topFile = imagecreatefromjpeg($strTopFilePath);
$bottomFile = imagecreatefromjpeg($strBottomFilePath);

list($intTopFileWidth, $intTopFileHeight) = getimagesize($strTopFilePath);
list($intBottomFileWidth, $intBottonFileHeight) = getimagesize($strBottomFilePath);

// compute new width/height
$intNewFileWidth = ($intTopFileWidth > $intBottomFileWidth) ? $intTopFileWidth : $intBottomFileWidth;     
$intNewFileHeight = $intTopFileHeight + $intBottonFileHeight;
// create new image and merge

$new = imagecreatetruecolor($intNewFileWidth, $intNewFileHeight);
imagecopy($new, $topFile, 0, 0, 0, 0, $intTopFileWidth, $intTopFileHeight);
imagecopy($new, $bottomFile, 0, $intTopFileHeight+1, 0, 0, $intBottomFileWidth, $intBottonFileHeight);
imagejpeg($new, $strMergedPath);
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you mean you expect to get something like the "merged image" you've posted,  but actually you've got a BLACK image after merging the two images by the PHP script ?

Comment: Could you describe what are you intending the merged images to look like?

Comment: @khartnett As you can see the black portion in my merged image which is not there in the actual image. I want an image without the black portion in my merged image. Here both the image dimensions are different.

Comment: I see, But please note that the width of the two images are NOT the same, so that's why there is a black region in the lower part because the lower part image is narrower than the upper part image. You have two choices, either (1) to crop the upper image to match the width of the lower image ; or (2) resize (enlarge) the lower image to meet the width of the upper image . But both methods will cause either information loss or distortion of the image(s)

Comment: @PrasanthKaki as Ken mentioned, you can crop or resize the images. Other options are to pick a different color. If you're looking to create an image with transparency, jpeg does not support that (but png does). Try imagepng($new, $strMergedPath); instead of imagejpeg($new, $strMergedPath);